# How can we create multiple indexes using CreateIndexModel in latest mongodb c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have to index 2 fields using `CreateIndexModel`, for single index I have tried this and its working.I am not sure how I can add one more field to index.

```
var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<BsonDocument>(
                Builders<BsonDocument>.IndexKeys.Ascending(IndexField),
                new CreateIndexOptions
                {
                    Name = IndexName,
                    Background = true
                });
            collection.Indexes.CreateOne(indexModel);
```

Answer (score 2):

if the goal is to create a compound index with multiple index keys, you can simply chain the builder methods like this:

```cs
Builders<Category>.IndexKeys
    .Ascending(x => x.Name)
    .Ascending(x => x.UserID);
```

just be aware that compound indexes have some limitations in mongo. just because you add all the fields of a query to an index doesn't mean they will all get used.

this [blog post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/performance-best-practices-indexing) will give you more info.